# How to give a table row a unique class name with Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table that is created by php looping through a mysql database and displaying images.
I want users to be able to click a button next to each image that they like and their username to appear below it without page refresh.

Currently in my jquery when the button is pressed the username appears below *all* the pictures because the table rows do not have unique class names. How can I get a username to only appear below the picture that was clicked?

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class ="tags">
            <?php 

            foreach($tag_array as $tag) {

                echo "
                <td>
                    <a href=\"profile.php?user_name=".$tag." \" 
                        <span class=\"label label-default\" id=\"tag\">".$tag."</span>
                    </a>";
            }
            echo "</td>
        </tr>";
}
echo "
    </tbody>
</table>";
}
?>
```

The jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myForm').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'add_tag.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                $('.tags').prepend(response);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: if you want to use unique identifiers use `ID` to make it unique use `index` to reference each table just add it to last character

Comment: Could you give me an example of how index is used?

Comment: have $i = 0; outside loop then before loop ends increment it then use that variable as index

Comment: I see. Something like this ` $('#<php echo $i?>').prepend(response);`

Comment: Ignore that, I think I get it after looking up index. Thanks.